# Trying to print JSON results from a webservice using hibernate and Spring

Tags: java, json, spring, hibernate

I have two projects defined 1) `GeneralOrm` which is used for general purpose web services and 2)`CompanyWS` which includes company specific webservices.
I am using Spring and Hibernate 4 version

I am writing a GET request to pull information based on two parameters namely, `employeeID` and `informationID`. There can only be one employeeID and multiple
informationID. Based on a employeeID and Information ID, I want to display the employeeID, INFORMATION_ID, VALUE_DISPLAY_NAME and value_emp_ID in my JSON result.

My table `EMP_METADATA` in the database looks like the following:

```
column_Name          Data_Type
EMPLOYEE_ID           NUMBER
INFORMATION_ID        NUMBER
VALUE_DISPLAY_NAME    VARCHAR2(30 BYTE)
VALUE_EMP_ID          NUMBER
```

Inside `CompanyWS` project, I have the GET request defined inside a controller in the following manner:

Inside package `CompanyWS` : `edu.abc.company.controller`

```
@RequestMapping(value="/get_em_metadata", method=RequestMethod.GET)

    public String getEmpMetaData 
    (
            @RequestParam(value="employee_id", defaultValue="0") Integer employeeID_,
            @RequestParam(value="information_id", defaultValue="0") Integer informationID_
    )
    {

        List<EmployeeMetaData> cvmetadata = null;
        GetEmployeeResult result = new GetEmployeeResult();
        try{

           EmployeeMetaDataDao rmDao =  (EmployeeMetaDataDao)context.getBean("EmployeeMetaDataDao");
           List<EmployeeMetaData> rm = rmDao.findByEmpAndInfoId(employeeID_, informationID_);
           if(rm != null) && (!rm.isEmpty()){


             System.out.println("Checking Aug 31:"+rm); // This works and print outs on the console
         }

        } catch(Throwable th) {
            th.printStackTrace();
            result.setWebServiceStatus(th.getMessage(), false);
        }

        //return result.toJSON();
    }
```

I am assuming that since my `System.out.print` statement is printing    the following on the console after running the webservice,

`Checking Aug 31:[edu.abc.company.orm.EmployeeMetaData@5963b830]`

I am half way through and I just need to print the result in the JSON format. In order to print the result, I have defined `GetEmployeeResult` which is as follows and extending the WebServiceResult class. I am wondering do I need to use `GetEmployeeResult` and extend `WebserviceResult` class or I can directly use WebServiceResult class inside my controller to 
print the results in JSON format? Any idea how should I proceed with the code for printing JSON inside controller. I have't used Hibernate before. Thanks in advance.

```
package edu.abc.company.json;
import java.util.List;
import edu.abc.company.domain.CvMetaDataList;
import edu.abc.company.domain.companyMetaDataList;
import edu.abc.company.util.WebServiceResult;

public class GetEmployeeResult extends WebServiceResult {

}
```

And here is the `WebServiceResult` class which is defined as follows:

```
package edu.abc.company.util;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.SerializationFeature;
import edu.abc.company.domain.StatusMessage;
import edu.abc.company.json.Views;


// A generic object that can be used to return data and a standardized status message from a web service.
public class WebServiceResult {

    protected StatusMessage webservice_status;

    // C-tor
    public WebServiceResult() {}

    // C-tor
    public WebServiceResult(StatusMessage webserviceStatus_) {
        webservice_status = webserviceStatus_;
    }

    // Web service status
    public StatusMessage getWebServiceStatus() {
        return webservice_status;
    }
    public void setWebServiceStatus(String message_, boolean success_) {
        webservice_status = new StatusMessage();
        if (success_) {         
            webservice_status.setStatus(Constants.SUCCESS); // Constants is another class which has messages defined, not including here
            webservice_status.setMessage(message_);
        } else {            
            webservice_status.setStatus(Constants.ERROR);
            webservice_status.setMessage(message_);
        }
    }

    // Export the object's contents as JSON.
    public String toJSON(boolean pretty_) {

        String json = "";

        try {
            ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();                     
            objectMapper.configure(SerializationFeature.INDENT_OUTPUT, pretty_);     

            // Convert the object to JSON.                                                      
            json = objectMapper.writerWithView(Views.Normal.class).writeValueAsString(this);
        }
        catch(Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return json;
    }

    public String toJSON() {
        return toJSON(true);
    }
}
```

The following are just for reference purpose in case someone is interested in looking at it:

I have defined the  `EmployeeMetaData`  inside the `GeneralOrm` project as follows:

Inside package `GeneralOrm` : `edu.abc.company.orm`

```
package edu.abc.company.orm;

import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.Table;

@Entity
@Table(name="EMP_METADATA") 
public class EmployeeMetaData 
{       
    public int getEmployeeId() {
        return employeeId;
    }

    public void setEmployeeId(int employeeId) {
        this.employeeId = employeeId;
    }

    public int getInformationId() {
        return informationId;
    }

    public void setInformationId(int informationId) {
        this.informationId = informationId;
    }


    public String getValueDisplayName() {
        return valueDisplayName;
    }

    public void setValueDisplayName(String valueDisplayName) {
        this.valueDisplayName = valueDisplayName;
    }

    public int getValueempId() {
        return valueempId;
    }

    public void setValueEmpId(int valueempId) {
        this.valueempId = valueempId;
    }



    @Id
    @Column(name="EMPLOYEE_ID")
    private int employeeId;

    @Column(name="INFORMATION_ID")
    private int informationId;

    @Column(name="VALUE_DISPLAY_NAME")
    private String valueDisplayName;

    @Column(name="VALUE_EMP_ID")
    private int valueempId;



}
```

I have defined the  `EmployeeMetaDataDao`  inside the `GeneralOrm` project as follows:

Inside project `GeneralOrm` : `edu.abc.company.orm.dao`

```
package edu.abc.company.orm.dao.impl;

import java.util.List;

import org.hibernate.Session;
import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext;
import edu.abc.company.orm.EmployeeMetaData;
import edu.abc.company.orm.dao.EmployeeMetaDataDao;

import edu.abc.company.util.Util;

public class EmployeeMetaDataDaoImpl implements EmployeeMetaDataDao {

    public void setSessionFactory(SessionFactory sessionFactory) {
        this.sessionFactory = sessionFactory;
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public List<EmployeeMetaData> list() {
        logger.debug("Starting EmployeeMetaDataDaoImpl.list() .....");
        Session session = null;

        List<EmployeeMetaData> EmployeeMetaData = null;
        try {
            session = this.sessionFactory.openSession();
            EmployeeMetaData = session.createQuery("FROM EmployeeMetaData").list();
        } catch(Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            session.close();
        }        
        logger.debug("Completed EmployeeMetaDataDaoImpl.list() .....");
        return EmployeeMetaData;
    }


    public List<EmployeeMetaData> findByEmpAndInfoId(int employee_id, int information_id) {
        List<EmployeeMetaData> EmployeeMetaData = null;
        Session session = null;
        try {
            session = this.sessionFactory.openSession();
            EmployeeMetaData = session.createQuery("FROM EmployeeMetaData WHERE information_id = '" + information_id + "'" + " AND company_id = '" + employee_id + "'").list();

        } catch(Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();           
        } finally {
            session.close();
        }

        return EmployeeMetaData;
    }

    // Main method goes here

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        ClassPathXmlApplicationContext context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("ApplicationContext.xml");

        try{
            EmployeeMetaDataDao rpcDao = (EmployeeMetaDataDao)context.getBean("EmployeeMetaDataDao"); 
            List<EmployeeMetaData> EmployeeMetaData = rpcDao.list();
            if ((EmployeeMetaData != null) && EmployeeMetaData.size() > 0) {
                for (int i=0;i<EmployeeMetaData.size();i++) {
                    EmployeeMetaData re = EmployeeMetaData.get(i);

                }
            }

            context.close();

        } catch(Throwable th) {
            th.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            context.close();
        }


    }

    private SessionFactory sessionFactory;
    private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(EmployeeMetaDataDaoImpl.class);

}
```

Comment: "public String getCvMetaData (change this before posting on SOF)" confusing.

Comment: I just changed .

Comment: @Dan may be this is https://www.mkyong.com/java/jackson-2-convert-java-object-to-from-json/ what you are looking for